# How to sort the rows of a 2D Matrix using qsort?

Tags: c, qsort

Many colleagues of mine were asking me if it is possible to sort each row of a 2D-Array, by using the function `qsort()` from `<stdlib.h>` to arrange a matrix like:

```
 5,  8,  7,  6, 
 1,  4,  3,  2, 
11, 12, 10,  9,
```

into something like:

```
 5,  6,  7,  8, 
 1,  2,  3,  4, 
 9, 10, 11, 12,
```

Comment: Sure, a row in a "2D array" it just a 1D array. You can sort each row just like you do any other array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qsorting 2d pointer arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673380/qsorting-2d-pointer-arrays)

Comment: @Code-Apprentice not exactly, this question is about an array of pointers ... but still I don't entirely get the point here.

Comment: @FelixPalmen The question does not give any declaration for the exact type of the 2D array. And the proposed solution does not say anything about pointers.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice huh? The question here is talking about a 2d-array and the proposed solution shows code handling a 2d-array. The "duplicate candidate" is about an array of pointers instead. As I said, I don't get the point here, but still this isn't an (exact) duplicate.

Comment: "this question is about an array of pointers" In the context, I took "this" to mean **this** question right here where we are commenting which has nothing to do with pointers. You are correct about **that** question which I proposed as a duplicate is about pointers. The confusion is cleared up for me now, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to the problem looks like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // scanf() printf()
#include <stdlib.h>  // qsort()

int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
{
  int x = *(int *)a;
  int y = *(int *)b;

  if (x<y) return -1; 
  if (x>y) return 1; 
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  // Syntax of a 2D Array: array[rows][cols]
  int rows = 3, cols = 4;
  int array[3][4] = { {5,8,7,6,}, {1,4,3,2}, {11,12,10,9} };

  // Print the matrix unsorted:
  printf("\nUnsorted rows:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      printf("%2d, ", array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  // Sort the matrix using qsort:
  for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++)
    qsort(array[j], cols, sizeof(int), compare);

  // Print the matrix sorted:
  printf("\nSorted rows:\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      printf("%2d, ", array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
Unsorted rows:
 5,  8,  7,  6, 
 1,  4,  3,  2, 
11, 12, 10,  9, 

Sorted rows:
 5,  6,  7,  8, 
 1,  2,  3,  4, 
 9, 10, 11, 12,
```

Thanks to **flukey** for the helpful answer in:
[Qsorting 2d pointer arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673380/qsorting-2d-pointer-arrays)

Comment: And what does this question/answer provide over the original you linked?

Comment: `compare` needs `{ }`

Comment: `return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );` <- beware of overflows.

Comment: @FelixPalmen do you know a better solution to overcome the problem of overflows?

Comment: @PatrickSteiner to keep it readable, do `int x = *(int *)a; int y = *(int *)b;`, then either `return (x>y) - (x<y);` or more verbose and a bit more readable with the same result `if (x<y) return -1; if (x>y) return 1; return 0;`

Comment: You should not cast away `const` in the compare function. A conversion from `const void*` to `int*` is not well-defined. You should have gotten compiler warnings. Cast to `const int*` instead.

Comment: @Lundin: Are you sure?  If the result of the cast was assigned to a pointer to non-const, then you'd have a case, but as it stands, it is fine, I believe.  (I think I recently saw a piece in the standard about this, but I've not been able to locate it again.  I'll replace this comment with another if I do get the x-ref.)

Comment: The alternative to the readable and extendable comparison scheme outlined by Felix is `return (x > y) - (x < y);` — which requires care to get the terms right and (at least until the optimizer gets to work) mandates two comparisons and a subtraction.  Be cautious about using this, but it does avoid overflows.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The conversion itself is undefined behavior since it is not covered by the C standard. 6.3.2.3/2 only mentions what is well-defined: `For any qualifier q, a pointer to a non-q-qualified type may be converted to a pointer to
the q-qualified version of the type; the values stored in the original and converted pointers
shall compare equal.` There is no documented behavior for the opposite: qualified-pointer-to-type converted to pointer-to-type. Void pointers should be no exception to the rule.

Comment: @Lundin: I'd found what you quote on my search while typing my previous comment about casts.  In §6.5.4 Cast operators, there is footnote 104: _A cast does not yield an lvalue. Thus, a cast to a qualified type has the same effect as a cast to the
unqualified version of the type._  Now, footnotes are not normative, so the quote you give of §6.3.2.2 ¶2 takes precedence over the footnote.  That means your comment is correct, I think.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler And for what it is worth, compilers and static analysers tend to moan if you have no cast and thereby force an implicit pointer conversion - since we're dealing with void pointers, the explicit cast shouldn't be needed. Unless it was purposely placed there to cast away the qualifier. Either way, it is bad practice and fishy code.

Answer (score 0):

Patrick,

Imagine the 2d array as a combination of many 1d arrays.

Perform a sort on each of the 1d arrays(rows), using 2 loops. One loop to iterate through the (columns) and one though the 1d arrays. In the second inner loop you can perform sorting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Since the sorting is to be done on each row, why do you propose iterating over columns?  How do you interpret `int array[3][4];` — an array of 3 rows with 4 columns per row, or something else?  Can you outline your code?  As it stands, your advice appears to be off-target.